# Skip arguments when executing functions in oracle

Tags: oracle11g, oracle12c, oracle19c

Simple question. I have a function as below

```
create or replace function f_blah (argfirst number default 5, argsecond number default 5) 
return number
AS

v_value number;
Begin
v_value := argfirst + argsecond;
return v_value;
END;
```

here are the results of my execution.

```
Select f_blah(1) from dual
```

result 6

```
Select f_blah() from dual
```

result 10

how to execute the function by giving the second argument alone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keyword/value notation with `Association Opeator` i.e., specify the argument name along with value by using `=>`

```
SELECT f_blah(argsecond=>4) FROM DUAL;
```

Output will be `9`

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=43fe5b3322c81311e888f1b740deb68e)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Hope there is no other easy way to execute it instead of  using argsecond=>

Comment: It is the easiest way that i know :)